# Why are field annotated with serialized names?

Tags: android, serialization

In the paging codelab there is this piece of code:

```
/**
 * Immutable model class for a Github repo that holds all the information about a repository.
 * Objects of this type are received from the Github API, therefore all the fields are annotated
 * with the serialized name.
 * This class also defines the Room repos table, where the repo [id] is the primary key.
 */
@Entity(tableName = "repos")
data class Repo(
        @PrimaryKey @field:SerializedName("id") val id: Long,
        @field:SerializedName("name") val name: String,
        @field:SerializedName("full_name") val fullName: String,
        @field:SerializedName("description") val description: String?,
        @field:SerializedName("html_url") val url: String,
        @field:SerializedName("stargazers_count") val stars: Int,
        @field:SerializedName("forks_count") val forks: Int,
        @field:SerializedName("language") val language: String?
)
```

Why are all those annotations needed? What do they do?

Comment: I mean...did you read the code comment......?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine this database record:

```
id: 21434366,
name: "John",
full_name: "John Doe",
number_of_github_repository: 4
```

The keys of each field is in lower case, underscore separated format. However, general naming convention of fields / variables are based on camel case.

Rather than using the field name itself as a variable name

```
val number_of_github_repository: Int
```

We all prefer this

```
val numOfGithubRepos: Int
```

That's where the @field:SerializedName annotation comes into play. If you annotate the variable name with the actual database field name, the program will find the value from the annotated name and assign it to your customized variable name.

For instance,

```
@field:SerializedName("number_of_github_repositories") val numOfGithubRepos: Int
```

This will look for the value from your database field, "number_of_github_repositories" and assign it to the variable numOfGithubRepos.

Same goes with the GSON library. It converts the unwanted/unorganized field names into your preferred variable names. By default, GSON library tries to look for the field from Json response that matches the declared variable name. So if you just declared the field without the annotation, like this,

```
val numOfGithubRepos: Int
```

and if the actual Json object was

```
{num_of_github_repositories: 4}
```

it will throw an exception since there's no such field with the name `numOfGithubRepos` in the Json response.

Answer (score 0):

They come from an api in form of a json. A json has a key-value structure, where you have the name and the value, so that annotation indicates what the key you're looking for and then the value is returned, in this case a long, strings and ints. I hope i was clear enough. =)